# How can I export MySQL database manually - without phpmyadmin

Tags: command-line, backup, mysql

My phpmyadmin doesn't work. I see only white blank page when I open it (it has some issue),

However, I'd like to export my project database manually to another computer.

I saw all my databases inside `/var/lib/mysql` and when i run

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename > backup.sql
```

using `mysqldump` for backing-up,  it freezes up and  does nothing

Is there any another way by which I can export my database?

Comment: I just wanted to say use `mysqldump`

Comment: Achu, have you tried looking at `mysql -u username -p -e 'show processlist'` ? It may offer a clue as to what mysqldump is waiting for. Could be a table lock.

Comment: This question is better suited for stackoverflow.com

Comment: It freezes because its creating the sql file. Just wait until it finishes.

Comment: "using mysqldump for backing-up, it freezes up and does nothing"  Open a 2nd terminal. cd to the dir you started the command and do `ls -l` Yoiu will see the file and it will be growing. ALSO: make sure you do this in a dir you own. Not in /var/lib/

Answer (score 22):

I have always used `mysqldump -u username -p databasename > backup.sql` with no issues.

Comment: This can be done from **$: /var/www**

Comment: No password for the db user?

Answer (score 0):

Just add **--no-tablespaces**, It's working for me

**mysqldump -u username --no-tablespaces -p databasename > backup.sql**

Comment: From the manual : `--no-tablespaces, -y This option suppresses all CREATE LOGFILE GROUP and CREATE TABLESPACE statements in the output of mysqldump. `  Why would this option prevent freeezing?